# I have this error "Invalid default value for 'CREATED' " in below query how to remove this

Tags: mysql

Here is my query:

```
CREATE TABLE `fisher`.`prodstock` (
  `PID` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Product Id',
  `QUANTITY` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Quantity in KG',
  `CREATED` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW() COMMENT 'Invard Quantity Date',
  PRIMARY KEY (`PID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_PID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`PID`)
    REFERENCES `fisher`.`products` (`PID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
COMMENT = 'Stock of Product'
```

Comment: What engine and version of MySQL

Answer (score 1):

set `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as default value.

```
CREATE TABLE `fisher`.`prodstock` (
  `PID` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Product Id',
  `QUANTITY` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Quantity in KG',
  `CREATED` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Invard Quantity Date',
  PRIMARY KEY (`PID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_PID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`PID`)
    REFERENCES `fisher`.`products` (`PID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
COMMENT = 'Stock of Product'
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `now()` function for default value. If you want to keep `DATETIME` datatype you have to create some trigger and used that whenever a record is inserted in the table. Default values always have to be a constant value, not the result of an expression.

Trigger example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `yourTriggername` BEFORE INSERT ON  `yourTablename` 
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.datetimefield = NOW()
```

If you can change the datatype for `created` to `timestamp` then you can use

```
CREATE TABLE fisher.prodstock (
 .....
    created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 ....
 )
```